# Como reemplazar un caracter según su posición en R

Tags: r, string, dataframe, estructuras-de-datos, datos

Estimados buenos días,

Estoy trabajando una base de datos pero me he encontrado con un problema quizás alguno por favor pueda ayudarme.

Tengo un data.frame y en una de las variables quiero cambiar la secuencia. mi variable inicial se ve así:

[image]

Cambio que deseo: El tercer dígito despues de "HI" quiero reemplazarlo por un guión y antes del último dígito quiero colocar un guión bajo. debería quedarme como sigue.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y muestra lo que has intentado hasta el momento. No olvides colocar el código y los ejemplos _como texto, con formato_. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una función propia con `gsub` y `sub` junto a expresiones regulares para realizar las órdenes que mencionas primero reemplazando el 3er carácters y luego añadiendo el guión bajo entre el punúltimo y último dígito:

```
Variable_1 <- c('HI11041','HI11052','HI21033')

reemplazo <- function(x){
  x <- gsub(pattern = 'HI[0123456789]',replacement = 'HI-',x = x)
  ultima <- sub(pattern = '.*(?=.$)',replacement = '',x = x, perl = T)
  gsub(pattern = '[0123456789]$',replacement = paste0('_',ultima),x = x)
}

sapply(Variable_1, reemplazo, USE.NAMES = F)
# [1] "HI-104_1" "HI-105_2" "HI-103_3"
```